# Javascript regex for string followed by exact number of chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I am looking for a regex for matching the following ids:

```
path-0
path-1
path-2
```

And does **not** match ids with a say bigger number of characters, eg:

```
path-0-0
path-0-1
```

Currently I have this chunk of code:

```js
let array = [
  'path-0', 'path-1', 'path-2', 'path-0-0', 'path-0-1'
];

let reg = /[^path-]{6}/;
    
$.each( array, function(index, value) {
  if(reg.test(value) ) {
    console.log(reg.test(value), value);  
  } else {
    console.error(reg.test(value), value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This `^path-\d$`?

Comment: Just FYI http://regexr.com is a great site for figuring out Regex patterns.

Comment: FYI `[^path-]` means match any character except what's in the set. So any character that isn't a character in `path-`, which is why you're getting all falses

Comment: The solution of ctwheels is working, thanks!

Comment: @IMLookingForAJob I converted my comments into an answer below (the one with two snippets)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you want to match beginning of string

```
^
```

Then the word "path" followed by a dash

```
^path-
```

Then a single character and nothing more (so, end of line)

```
^path-\d$
```

As per Arthur's comment, if your intention is to allow ids with more than one digit after "path-" you can specify that you want 1 or more digits by suffixing `\d` with `+`, like this:

```
^path-\d+$
```

Comment: Won't match path-10

Comment: OP didn't ask for it. Actually, they said "And does not match ids with a say bigger number of characters"

Comment: If you think in the context of IDs you can for sure induce that IDs may be any integer greater than 0, not limited by example. Just preventing future bugs

Comment: I understand your point, just commenting to give you the chance to improve your answer. I think it's clear that what was intended in the question, checking the following examples, that 'bigger number of characters' was about non-digit chars.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to check if pattern `/-\d+/` only occurs once. Notice that the symbol `+` here works to match numbers with more than one digit. You need though to check for string end, represented by `$` symbol, the same way `^` represents the beginning of it. The best regex option that will work for you would be:

```
let reg = /^path-\d+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

**As per my original comments...**

The reason your pattern `[^path-]` is not working is because it matches anything not present in the set, so any character except `ahpt-` (I rearranged the characters so you can better understand what it's saying). Character sets are used when you want to say *match anything that is (or is not) in this set*.

An example of using a set, for your example, would be `^path-[0-9]$`. This says *match a character between `0` and `9` in the ASCII table, which includes `0123456789`. Another way of defining the same character set is using the shorthand token `\d` (which specifies the same characters `0` through `9`).

The caret symbol `^` used at the start of a set specifies that the set should negate these characters. An example of its use for your example is `^path-[^\D]$`, which is basically a double-negative specifying anything that is not not a digit (or simply put any digit). Anywhere outside a set (and assuming it's not escaped) `^` means *assert position at the start of the string*.

### Code

```
^path-\d$
```

```js
let array = [
  'path-0', 'path-1', 'path-2', 'path-0-0', 'path-0-1', 'path-12'
];

let reg = /^path-\d$/;
    
$.each( array, function(index, value) {
  if(reg.test(value) ) {
    console.log(reg.test(value), value);  
  } else {
    console.error(reg.test(value), value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to match the possibility of more than 1 digit, you can use the following.

```
^path-\d+$
```

```js
let array = [
  'path-0', 'path-1', 'path-2', 'path-0-0', 'path-0-1', 'path-12'
];

let reg = /^path-\d+$/;
    
$.each( array, function(index, value) {
  if(reg.test(value) ) {
    console.log(reg.test(value), value);  
  } else {
    console.error(reg.test(value), value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the string
- `path-` Match this literally
- `\d` Match any digit
- `$` Assert position at the end of the string